How to avoid Whisper model loading to slow when other processes running
I am currently working on a flask API which loads and inferences models when requested.
Only 1 model is loaded at a time, so while 1 request is being resolved the rest of requests are waiting for their turn.
The Problem is that Whisper seems to slow absurdly when there are other processes runnig, even if they are not taking resources, so i was wondering if there is any solution.
Making it sequential wouldnt solve it, because even though I am solving requests 1 by 1, I am using a priority Queue that orders the requests, so making it sequential would make the queue useless
I tried using 1 thread, and it solved it, but this would make the API sequential, which would again ruin my queue.
I need to keep threads working, and Whisper to not slowdown.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  As it currently stands, your question doesn't make it clear what exactly you are asking. If you have a problem with getting python threading to do what you want, I suggest you post some code (ideally a Minimal Reproducible Example). If you're worried about performance or having trouble with interfacing Flask with your threading code, I suggest to edit your question to focus on that.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
